# Tableau Filters Enabled/Disabled based on another control

Tags: tableau-api

I have a single data source and multiple sets of filters into my dashboard based on the same data source. When a particular set of filters is selected I want to disable the other set of filters. Is there any way I can work this out on a Tableau dashboard.
For Ex. There are 5 groups of filters A, B, C, D, E.
I want to give my users the options to select the filters from Group A or Group B. So when the filters from Group A are selected the filters from Group B should automatcally be disabled.

Thanks n advance